# PHP no me toma el css

Tags: php, css

Estoy con un problema en mi pagina web la cual cuando desde un metodo del controlador que invoca vistas no me esta incluyendo el

```
public function listProducts()
        {
          try
          {
          require_once("nav-bar-admin.php");
          require_once("footer-admin.php");

          }
          catch(Exception $ex)
        {
          $message = 'Oops ! \n\n Hubo un problema al intentar mostrar la Pagina.\n Consulte a su Administrador o vuelva a intentarlo.';
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">confirm("'.$message.'");</script>';
          require_once("home.php");
        }
      }
```

El codigo del nav Bar:

```
<?php

    include_once('header.php');

 ?>

<body class="animsition">

    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="header1">
        <!-- Header desktop -->
        <div class="container-menu-header">
            <div class="topbar">
                <div class="topbar-social">
                    <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-facebook"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-instagram"></a>
            <!--        <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-pinterest-p"></a>  -->
            <!--        <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a> -->
                    <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-youtube-play"></a>
                </div>

                <span class="topbar-child1">
                    Bienvenidos
                </span>

                <div class="topbar-child2">
                    <span class="topbar-email">
                        santaola@gmail.com
                    </span>

            <!--        <div class="topbar-language rs1-select2">
                        <select class="selection-1" name="time">
                            <option>USD</option>
                            <option>EUR</option>
                        </select>
                    </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap_header hoverini" style="background-color:#f5f5f5">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <a href="index2.php" class="logo" style="font-size: 32px">
                    SANTA OLA SURFSHOP
                <!--    <img src="images/icons/logo.png" alt="IMG-LOGO"> -->
                </a>

                <!-- Menu -->
                <div class="wrap_menu">
                    <nav class="menu">
                        <ul class="main_menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo FRONT_ROOT ?>Product/listProducts">ARTÍCULOS</a>
                        <!--        <ul class="sub_menu">
                                    <li><a href="index.php">Homepage V1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="home-02.php">Homepage V2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="home-03.php">Homepage V3</a></li>
                                </ul>   -->
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="sponsor-admin.php">RAIDERS</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="event-admin.php">EVENTOS</a>

                            </li>
                    <!--        <li class="sale-noti">
                                <a href="product.php">Sale</a>
                            </li>   -->

                            <!--                <li>
                                <a href="cart.php">Features</a>
                            </li>
                            -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="carousel-admin.php">CAROUSEL</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="nuevos-admin.php">NUEVOS</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="contact-admin.php">CONTACTO</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <!-- Header Icon
                <div class="header-icons">
                    <a href="#" class="header-wrapicon1 dis-block">
                        <img src="images/icons/icon-header-01.png" class="header-icon1" alt="ICON">
                    </a>

                    <span class="linedivide1"></span>

                    <div class="header-wrapicon2">
                        <img src="images/icons/icon-header-02.png" class="header-icon1 js-show-header-dropdown" alt="ICON">
                        <span class="header-icons-noti">0</span>

                         Header cart noti
                <div class="header-cart header-dropdown">
                            <ul class="header-cart-wrapitem">
                                <li class="header-cart-item">
                                    <div class="header-cart-item-img">
                                        <img src="images/item-cart-01.jpg" alt="IMG">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="header-cart-item-txt">
                                        <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name">
                                            White Shirt With Pleat Detail Back
                                        </a>

                                        <span class="header-cart-item-info">
                                            1 x $19.00
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="header-cart-item">
                                    <div class="header-cart-item-img">
                                        <img src="images/item-cart-02.jpg" alt="IMG">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="header-cart-item-txt">
                                        <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name">
                                            Converse All Star Hi Black Canvas
                                        </a>

                                        <span class="header-cart-item-info">
                                            1 x $39.00
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="header-cart-item">
                                    <div class="header-cart-item-img">
                                        <img src="images/item-cart-03.jpg" alt="IMG">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="header-cart-item-txt">
                                        <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name">
                                            Nixon Porter Leather Watch In Tan
                                        </a>

                                        <span class="header-cart-item-info">
                                            1 x $17.00
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <div class="header-cart-total">
                                Total: $75.00
                            </div>

                            <div class="header-cart-buttons">
                                <div class="header-cart-wrapbtn">
                                     Button
                                    <a href="cart.php" class="flex-c-m size1 bg1 bo-rad-20 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                                        View Cart
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="header-cart-wrapbtn">
                                     Button
                                    <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size1 bg1 bo-rad-20 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                                        Check Out
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Header Mobile -->
        <div class="wrap_header_mobile">
            <!-- Logo moblie -->
            <a href="index.php" class="logo-mobile">
                <img src="images/icons/logo.png" alt="IMG-LOGO">
            </a>

            <!-- Button show menu -->
            <div class="btn-show-menu">
                <!-- Header Icon mobile -->
                <div class="header-icons-mobile">
                    <a href="#" class="header-wrapicon1 dis-block">
                        <img src="images/icons/icon-header-01.png" class="header-icon1" alt="ICON">
                    </a>

                    <span class="linedivide2"></span>

                    <div class="header-wrapicon2">
                        <img src="images/icons/icon-header-02.png" class="header-icon1 js-show-header-dropdown" alt="ICON">
                        <span class="header-icons-noti">0</span>

                        <!-- Header cart noti -->
                        <div class="header-cart header-dropdown">
                            <ul class="header-cart-wrapitem">
                                <li class="header-cart-item">
                                    <div class="header-cart-item-img">
                                        <img src="images/item-cart-01.jpg" alt="IMG">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="header-cart-item-txt">
                                        <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name">
                                            White Shirt With Pleat Detail Back
                                        </a>

                                        <span class="header-cart-item-info">
                                            1 x $19.00
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="header-cart-item">
                                    <div class="header-cart-item-img">
                                        <img src="images/item-cart-02.jpg" alt="IMG">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="header-cart-item-txt">
                                        <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name">
                                            Converse All Star Hi Black Canvas
                                        </a>

                                        <span class="header-cart-item-info">
                                            1 x $39.00
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="header-cart-item">
                                    <div class="header-cart-item-img">
                                        <img src="images/item-cart-03.jpg" alt="IMG">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="header-cart-item-txt">
                                        <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name">
                                            Nixon Porter Leather Watch In Tan
                                        </a>

                                        <span class="header-cart-item-info">
                                            1 x $17.00
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <div class="header-cart-total">
                                Total: $75.00
                            </div>

                            <div class="header-cart-buttons">
                                <div class="header-cart-wrapbtn">
                                    <!-- Button -->
                                    <a href="cart.php" class="flex-c-m size1 bg1 bo-rad-20 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                                        View Cart
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="header-cart-wrapbtn">
                                    <!-- Button -->
                                    <a href="#" class="flex-c-m size1 bg1 bo-rad-20 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                                        Check Out
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-show-menu-mobile hamburger hamburger--squeeze">
                    <span class="hamburger-box">
                        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Menu Mobile -->
        <div class="wrap-side-menu" >
            <nav class="side-menu">
                <ul class="main-menu">
                    <li class="item-topbar-mobile p-l-20 p-t-8 p-b-8">
                        <span class="topbar-child1">
                            Bienvenidos
                        </span>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-topbar-mobile p-l-20 p-t-8 p-b-8">
                        <div class="topbar-child2-mobile">
                            <span class="topbar-email">
                                santaola@gmail.com
                            </span>

        <!--                    <div class="topbar-language rs1-select2">
                                <select class="selection-1" name="time">
                                    <option>USD</option>
                                    <option>EUR</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>  -->
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-topbar-mobile p-l-10">
                        <div class="topbar-social-mobile">
                            <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-facebook"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-instagram"></a>
                <!--            <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-pinterest-p"></a>  -->
                <!--            <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a> -->
                            <a href="#" class="topbar-social-item fa fa-youtube-play"></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-menu-mobile">
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="index.php">Homepage V1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="home-02.php">Homepage V2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="home-03.php">Homepage V3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <i class="arrow-main-menu fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-menu-mobile">
                        <a href="product.php">SHOP</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-menu-mobile">
                        <a href="product.php">Sale</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-menu-mobile">
                        <a href="cart.php">Features</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-menu-mobile">
                        <a href="blog.php">Blog</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-menu-mobile">
                        <a href="about.php">About</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="item-menu-mobile">
                        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

El codigo del footer :

```
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".selection-1").select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: 20,
    dropdownParent: $('#dropDownSelect1')
  });
</script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick-custom.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/lightbox2/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.block2-btn-addcart').each(function(){
    var nameProduct = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.block2-name').php();
    $(this).on('click', function(){
      swal(nameProduct, "is added to cart !", "success");
    });
  });

  $('.block2-btn-addwishlist').each(function(){
    var nameProduct = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.block2-name').php();
    $(this).on('click', function(){
      swal(nameProduct, "is added to wishlist !", "success");
    });
  });
</script>

<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

y del header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.png"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/themify/themify-icons.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/Linearicons-Free-v1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/elegant-font/html-css/style.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/slick/slick.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/lightbox2/css/lightbox.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
```

Consola de la pagina:
El js es del template descargado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya revisaste que lo que arroja el inspector de elementos de tu navegador? tal vez ahí encontremos el problema.

Comment: @matteo ahi pego una foto en la pregunta asi la ves

Comment: 1.-¿Puedes mostrar como queda el código fuente de tu página?
2.-Intenta poner tus scripts después de que todos tus archivos JS hayan sido cargados.
3.-Intenta separar tu header de tu Nav-bar.

Comment: Éste parece (y estoy casi seguro que es) el típico problema que sucede cuando se usan rutas relativas en un sitio con páginas a diferentes niveles. Como estás cargando todo el CSS y JS usando rutas relativas, sólo te van a funcionar a un nivel (me imagino que la raíz o el primer nivel "SantaOla"), pero estás abriendo la página /SantaOla/Product/listProducts que tiene 2 niveles. Eso va a hacer que no funcione bien porque los ficheros no están donde deberían estar. Usa rutas absolutas o relativas a la raíz para que te tome los ficheros CSS y JS correctamente.

Comment: Gracias a todos, me oriente con el tema de Rutas absolutas y relativas @AlvaroMontoro si lo pones como respuesta, lo marco como valida.